# Fluid obstacles ignored

Tags: fluid-simulation

I am learning the fluid physics function. Blender primitives like cube and sphere work for obstacles but if I make a 3d part in inventor and import it as an fbx file and make it an obstacle, blender fluids ignore the object. Any idea what I might be doing wrong or does blender not recognize 3D objects not native to blender?

Comment: Hi, welcome. Have you checked the most obvious reasons: old caching, transforms not applied, inverted normals...? or, can you share an example file  (eg: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) ?

Comment: Hi, Ok I am amazed at the quick response.  Thanks!  I am really new at this.  Can I upload the blender test.  (It is really low tech test...nothing fancy)

Comment: Ignore my question of the obvious  I will try uploading it thanks.  Val